# Why is there a major difference in the React code on codecademy vs the docs

Tags: reactjs

New to react and never used much js. Noticed a large difference in the react code on codecademy vs the react docs. Just wondering why this is, and which type is best to follow.

Comment: Is there a specific piece of code you want to ask about?

Comment: Put the two codes & Your concern about each one , then , I will give you a cool answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that codecademy uses the old style `const MyComponent = React.createClass({ ... })`. This is now deprecated in favour of es6 classes, e.g. `class MyComponent extends React.Component { ... }`. I would recommend the es6 approach, but if you must use `React.createClass` for whatever reason, the react docs explain how to do that [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html).